# Help about NAT with virtual server

Tags: linux, virtualization

I have a dedicated server running Linux CentOS 5.3 with 2 IP addresses. I've installed a virtual machine using VMware Server. The host and the guest have a host-only network. Now I want to map the 2nd IP address to the virtual machine so that it can run as a second dedicated server for me. Here is what I do:

```
modprobe iptable_nat

echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -s 192.168.78.128 -d 64.85.164.184 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 64.85.164.184 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.78.128

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.78.128 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 64.85.164.184</p>
```

But it not working as intended. What is the matter?

Comment: Any reason you can't set the guest up with a bridged network configuration? (VMWare Fusion offers this method, I assume VMWare Server does too)

Comment: the server provider assign 2 IP address on my host computer. And if I user bridged network, my virtual machine can not get IP address, neither via DHCP nor assigned manually

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to set up the #2 server on VMWare to use NAT Mode (example of how to setup is here http://www.virtuatopia.com/index.php/VMware_Server_NAT_Configuration).
After that setup the iptables with

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.78.128
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -o eth0 -p tcp -j SNAT --to-source 64.85.164.184
```

You can test by pinging the gateway of 64.85.164.184 network from inside VMWare Server #2

Comment: Thanks, but look like this way all traffic will route to my #2 server and how about the host machine ?